# meet some condition bar by bar in pine script

Tags: pine-script

How to check if some condition is met on each bar?
I want to check crossover of slow and fast EMA when each bar is completed (bar by bar) until crossover is happened. I don't have any idea about this and it is appreciate to tell how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `if` operator and `crossover` function

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#if-statement
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_crossover

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

ema10 = ema(close, 10)
ema20 = ema(close, 20)
plot(ema10, color = color.red)
plot(ema20, color = color.green)

if crossover(ema10,ema20)
    label.new(bar_index, high, text = "Crossover ema10 over ema20")
```

Comment: No, because no data available from the future. You can plot something into future (lines, labels) but with respect of the data that is available in the moment at which your script is calculating (real time or history bars).

Comment: Dear Starr Lucky, thanks for your answer. How can I determine bars between two EMA cross? i.e. determine area between a consecutive undercross and overcross?

Comment: `barssince(crossover)` counts the number of bars since the last time the `crossover` condition was true. So it crossover of two emas is in the current bar, where calculation occurs, then barssince(crossover) = 0.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v1/#fun_barssince 

Same you can do for the `crossunder` and then count bars in this area.

Comment: i.e. (barssince(crossover) - barssince(crossunder))

Comment: Is it possible to do it with finding bar_index and valuewhen() function?

Comment: `valuewhen()` is for finding float values, you can find some price value after crossover, but why?

Comment: I want to find bars between two consecutive cross, i.e. a crossover before a crossunder or a crossunder before a crossover. Is it possoible by finding: bi = valuewhen(crossover, bar_index, 0), and then find bar_index greater than bi until a crossunder is happening?